# vite & react import images dynamically from public url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I would like to import images dynamically from the public folder, but this isn't working- anyone know why?

```
const modules = import.meta.glob("/Images/*.jpg");
const imagePaths = [];
for (const path in modules) {
    modules[path]().then(() => {
        const p = new URL(path, import.meta.url);
        const data = {
            path: p.pathname,
        };
        imagePaths.push(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to adjust the path that you pass to the `import.meta.glob` function. Specify a path relative to the file that this code is in, since "/Images/*.jpg" will refer to the root folder on your system (because it starts with a slash).

Next you can use {eager: true} option to resolve the promise at compile time (you import just the URL, no need to use code splitting).

```js
const imagePaths = [];
//          note relative path vvv                 vvv this gets rid of promises
Object.values(import.meta.glob("./assets/*.jpg", { eager: true })).forEach(
  ({ default: path }) => {
    const url = new URL(path, import.meta.url);
    const data = {
      path: url.pathname,
    };
    imagePaths.push(data);
  }
);

/* imagePaths will have content like this:
[ {"path":"/src/assets/logo.jpg"}, {"path":"/src/assets/logo.jpg"} ]
*/
```

You can also take a look at the documentation here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! The docs say that there can be no dynamic imports from public urls, so I appreciate you showing me how its done properly.